# Graphing Program in Python (3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I've been trying to make a GUI in Python that will take 3 numbers as user input and graph them in a 3D scatter plot. i've been successful in creating the GUI through tkinter, but I'm stuck when it comes to actual graphing. I wanted to define an empty list for x, y, and z variables, then append them with whatever the user inputs. I would then take those variables and have matplotlib graph them. I was unable to do it as originally planned, so I reverted to defining two functions, each tied to their own buttons. The "store" button would record the user input into the respective empyt lists created beforehand and clear the entry box. Then, the user could hit the graph button and the lists would be graphed in a 3D plot. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#store function
x_List = []
y_List = []
z_List = []

def store():
    x_List.append(x_Var)
    y_List.append(y_Var)
    z_List.append(z_Var)
    entry_1.delete(0, END)
    entry_2.delete(0, END)
    entry_3.delete(0, END)

def graph():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    X = x_List
    Y = y_List
    Z = z_List

    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='b', marker='o')

    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')

    plt.show()

home = Tk()
home.title("Graph")
homeLabel = Label(home, text="Graph Program").grid(row=0, column=1)
home.minsize(600,600)
home.maxsize(600,600)

#entry boxes and labels
intel = StringVar()
person = StringVar()
attractive = StringVar()
label_1 = Label(home, text="X:").grid(row=2, column=0)
label_2 = Label(home, text="Y:").grid(row=3, column=0)
label_3 = Label(home, text="Z:").grid(row=4, column=0)
entry_1 = Entry(home, textvariable=x_Var)
entry_1.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry_2 = Entry(home, textvariable=y_Var)
entry_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
entry_3 = Entry(home, textvariable=z_Var)
entry_3.grid(row=4, column=1)

#buttons
storeButton = Button(home, text="Store", command=store).grid(row=5, column=0)
graphButton = Button(home, text="Graph", command=graph).grid(row=5, column=1)

home.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you looked at http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html

Comment: My main issue has been with the storage function. I keep getting the error back that x_List is undefined.